# How to change role titles in Bbpress?

Tags: bbpress

Default role titles in BBpress are "Keymaster" and "Participant".

I want to change them. I tried the solutions in this [page](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/not-working-for-bbpress-roles) but they didn't work in my bbpress. Probably, the solutions are for old versions of bbpress. I have version 2.2.x.

How can I change role labels in bbpress?

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried this plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/bbpress-string-swap/ ?

Or if you want to code, you could use this snippet in which you can change names. You should insert it into your functions.php

```
add_filter( 'bbp_get_dynamic_roles', 'my_bbp_custom_role_names');

function my_bbp_custom_role_names(){
 return array(

        // Keymaster
        bbp_get_keymaster_role() => array(
            'name'         => __( 'Keymaster', 'bbpress' ),
            'capabilities' => bbp_get_caps_for_role( bbp_get_keymaster_role() )
        ),

        // Moderator
        bbp_get_moderator_role() => array(
            'name'         => __( 'Moderator', 'bbpress' ),
            'capabilities' => bbp_get_caps_for_role( bbp_get_moderator_role() )
        ),

        // Participant
        bbp_get_participant_role() => array(
            'name'         => __( 'Participant', 'bbpress' ),
            'capabilities' => bbp_get_caps_for_role( bbp_get_participant_role() )
        ),

        // Spectator
        bbp_get_spectator_role() => array(
            'name'         => __( 'Spectator', 'bbpress' ),
            'capabilities' => bbp_get_caps_for_role( bbp_get_spectator_role() )
        ),

        // Blocked
        bbp_get_blocked_role() => array(
            'name'         => __( 'Blocked', 'bbpress' ),
            'capabilities' => bbp_get_caps_for_role( bbp_get_blocked_role() )
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work neither. I put the code into functions.php of my theme. But role labels are still the same.

Comment: Cuz there was an error in the code - one extra bracket. And you have to rewrite 'name' é> 'Keymaster' to whatever you like. Give it a try again.